# How to load packages in R automatically?

Tags: r, loading, r-package, r-faq, defaults

Could you suggest me a way for loading packages in R automatically? I mean, I want to start a session in R without needing to use `library('package name')` several times. Suppose I downloaded all packages I'll want to use the next time I start R.

Comment: Normally this is not a good idea because it makes all subsequent code in the session dependent on your setup whereas if it had the library calls in it then it would be more self-contained.  If you try to share your code with others they will not be very happy with you since they won't be able to run your scripts without additional instructions.

Comment: You could define a `load_extra_packages()` function in your `.Rprofile`/`Rprofile.site` file that loaded all of the packages you wanted (and printed out their names), then run that command at the beginning of your sessions -- that would make your code transparent, if not completely self-contained ...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Put `library(foo)` in your `.Rprofile` file or set `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES`: see `?Rprofile` ...

In particular (because `?Rprofile` is long and potentially intimidating):

> If you want a different set of packages than the default ones when you
>   start, insert a call to ‘options’ in the ‘.Rprofile’ or
>   ‘Rprofile.site’ file.  For example, ‘options(defaultPackages =
>   character())’ will attach no extra packages on startup (only the
>   ‘base’ package) (or set ‘R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL’ as an environment
>   variable before running R).  Using ‘options(defaultPackages = "")’ or
>   ‘R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=""’ enforces the R *system* default.

Since you probably *do* want all of the default packages loaded, and then extra ones in addition (rather than, say, not loading some of the default packages), you can either put

```
library("mypackage1")
library("mypackage2")
[etc.]
```

or using `options(defaultPackages=...)`:

```
options(defaultPackages=c(getOption("defaultPackages"),
       "mypackage1","mypackage2", ... [etc.]))
```

in your `.Rprofile` to *append* your desired packages to the standard defaults.

**edit** (copied from comment) re getting this to work in [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.org): 
http://rstudio.org/docs/using/workspaces suggests that Rstudio executes `.Rprofile` and then "Performs the other actions described in R Startup [ http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Startup.html ]" (which is the same as `?Rprofile`). It is ambiguous whether it looks at `Rprofile.site` or not.

**edit #2**: according to comment below, it does work with a recent version of Rstudio.

Comment: +1 for 'because `?Rprofile` is long and potentially intimidating'. It is that, and also a terrifically compact *and* complete piece of documentation. Definitely recommended reading.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker I tried adding this line `library(foo)` in the `Rprofile.site` file and I'm no getting what I want. What do you mean with `foo`? What is that? Is it supposed to be a name for a determined package I want to load?

Comment: sorry; `foo` is an old-fashioned "placeholder" variable.  For example, you might try `library("ggplot2"); library("emdbook"); library("quantreg"); library("rms")` (as examples of some real packages you might want to include).

Comment: Ok I appreciate your help in this case @BenBolker. Do you know how to do the same but with Rstudio?

Comment: I would expect that Rstudio would respect your Rprofile.site settings, but to be honest I'm not sure. Have you confirmed that you've got something working with the standard Rgui and that it *doesn't* work with Rstudio?

Comment: Yes @BenBolker, I tried putting this line `options(defaultPackages=c(getOption("defaultPackages"),
       "tm","plyr","twitteR","sqldf"))` in my `Rprofile.site` and it's worked great using the standard Rgui. However, when I start Rstudio, those packages are not loaded. Many thanks!

Comment: http://rstudio.org/docs/using/workspaces suggests that Rstudio executes `.Rprofile` and then "Performs the other actions described in R Startup [ http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Startup.html ]" (which is the same as `?Rprofile`). It is ambiguous whether it looks at `Rprofile.site` or not.  I would (1) try putting the startup code in your `.Rprofile` (rather than `Rprofile.site`); if that doesn't work, (2) update your question above to reflect this issue, and (3) ask at http://support.rstudio.org/ (referencing this question)

Comment: Many thanks once again @BenBolker. I solved this issue by updating my Rstudio version and using the line `options(defaultPackages=c(getOption("defaultPackages"), "tm","plyr","twitteR","sqldf"))` in my Rprofile.site as you suggested me.

Comment: @BenBolker, this doesn't seem to work with packages with inter-dependencies. Say package `A` depends on package `B` (with the DESCRIPTION file reflecting this). Putting `library(A)` in the .Rprofile script causes an error to occur when installing package `B`. The same error occurs if I include `library(B)` or change the `defaultPackages` option instead. The exact error when installing package `B` is `Error: package ‘B’ is required by ‘A’ so will not be detached`.

Comment: This strikes me as a little bit of a "well, don't do that then" situation ... I would normally expect that you would install packages **before** putting them in your `.Rprofile`.  If you have a sensible use case for this, I would suggest asking it as another question ...

Comment: I was using it during debugging. Essentially, I would edit and re-install the library frequently. Having the libraries automatically load saves me time when beginning a new R session.

Comment: Indeed, R (studio) will load base packages after reading .Rprofile, so updating packages is safer, see my post below.

Comment: Execute path.expand("~") to see where you need to put your ..Rprofile file

Answer (score 17):

There is a file called .Rprofile that is nothing but a script that is run everytime you start a new session of R.

What you need to do is add `library(package)` to it. If you're using Unix, it's probably on your home folder as a hidden file.

Answer (score 10):

[Quick-R page on customizing R startup](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html) contains basically the same information than in Ben's and Joao's answers, but it is perhaps a bit clearer. Create a copy of `Rprofile.site` file with desired changes in your home folder (Documents on Windows) and call it `.Rprofile`

**EDIT:** I noticed that R 3.0.0 does not look from Documents folder any longer, but uses user's home directory (user name) under Windows 7. This might be an installation issue, though (i.e. that I happened to install R "wrongly" previously). However, the Quick-R page linked in this answer tells the right way of doing this. If somebody else is encountering this problem, the solution is to copy `.Rprofile` to the user's home directory.

Answer (score 8):

The quick answer is that you should put your R packages in the `.Rprofile` file, as everyone suggested.

Note however that R will read this file, and **then load the R base packages**. See from [?Startup](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Startup.html):

> Note that when the site and user profile files are sourced only the
>   base package is loaded,

This can cause problems if the package you want to load enhances/overwrite some R base functions. See for example with tidyverse::filter: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1611

I can see two solutions so far:

1. Use `.First.sys()` at the first line of your `.Rprofile` file: this is the command that is usually run after reading the .Rprofile, that loads the packages in `getOption("defaultPackages")`.
2. Update the option *defaultPackages*: don't use `library()` in your .Rprofile, but something like.

   ```
   old <- getOption("defaultPackages")
   options(defaultPackages = c(old, "tidyverse"))
   ```

Comment: This answer identified something that others did not: the importance of the order of loading and it's impact on overwriting of functions (e.g. `plot` vs `sp::plot`).   The `.First.sys()` solution saved me a lot of headache...  Thanks!