# Loading libraries in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, package

New to RStudio. Is there a way to efficiently load libraries in scripts so I don’t have to write out the names of the packages for every new script like this…

```
library(‘ggplot2‘)
library(‘dplyr‘) 
library(‘lubridate‘) 
library(‘tidyr‘)
library(‘stringr‘)
```

And so on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might also consider automatically loading packages on startup of a project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14238658/2706826

Comment: And if you're gonna accept an answer, consider giving it an upvote..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function in each script. Add the names of new libraries as required.

```
libraries <- c('ggplot2', 'dplyr', 'lubridate', 'tidyr', 'stringr')

lapply(libraries, FUN = function(y) {
    do.call('require', list(y))})
```

Comment: or just `sapply(libraries, require,character.only = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

1) create an .R file with the following, in this example the name of the file will be 'libraries.R'

```
library(‘ggplot2‘)
library(‘dplyr‘) 
library(‘lubridate‘) 
library(‘tidyr‘)
library(‘stringr‘)
```

2) source that file in every script you use

```
source('libraries.R')
```