# KS library in R and using geospatial modelling environment

Tags: r, geospatial, arcgis, kernel-density

I am using the latest R package and geosptaial modelling environment 0.7.3 to create kernel density estimates for the data I have. When I try to install the kernelsmooth package, I get this:

packages("ks", dependencies=TRUE) library("ks")
Error: unexpected symbol in "install.packages("ks", dependencies=TRUE) library"

I have installed the ks package, but not the library.
When I try to create a KDE in GME, it says it could not create a KDE because 'the ks library does not appear to be installed in R. Please install it and rerun this command.'

Anyone know how to rectify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You either need to seperate your commands with a `;` or put them on different lines:

`install.packages("ks", dependencies=TRUE); library("ks")`

```
install.packages("ks", dependencies=TRUE)
library("ks")
```

Comment: I separated them and it says: package ‘ks’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked. But then it says -  library("ks")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ks’

Comment: Try installing and loading Rcpp the same way you did ks, I would think that loading ks would have done that but it appears not.

Comment: I installed Rcpp and this came up - package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked, so then I ran the ks package again, but I got the same error message above

Comment: Run `find.package("Rcpp")` and `find.package("ks")` to make sure they're installed in the same directory.

Comment: > find.package("Rcpp")
Error in find.package("Rcpp") : there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
> find.package("ks")
[1] "C:/Users/Penny/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/ks"                                       that's what I'm getting

Comment: It looks like Rccp I would try running `install.packages("Rccp")` again. If that doesn't work I'm out of suggestions maybe someone else has a different idea.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407092/r-not-finding-package-even-after-package-installation