# R not finding installed packages in OneDrive

Tags: r, tidyverse, onedrive

I have just changed laptops and I saved all my R files in OneDrive. I am trying to run my previous R scripts but I get stuck from the very first lines when I load the libraries:

> Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called
> ‘tidyverse’

Then, I ran `.libpaths()`, and I tried to delete the tidyverse file from there but I cannot: for some reason, even when I pause syncing the OneDrive, the tidyverse file is stuck on the 'sync pending' sign.

No idea how to fix this and run my scripts again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it - in case someone else is facing the same issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMd2s1Em42Q - I was getting this 'tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid' error too when trying to open the tidyverse file. Once I've followed the YouTube video instructions, I managed to delete the tidyverse file and then follow the instructions from here: [R not finding package even after package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407092/r-not-finding-package-even-after-package-installation)

Now tidyverse works!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).