# Problems with OneDrive and finding contemporary solution

Tags: r, onedrive

I have to use OneDrive for my work but it seems to cause problems with R and in particular the install.packages aspect as these seem to default to OneDrive in a way which is unchangeable.
I have read some possible solution to this at https://medium.com/@ValidScience/how-to-fix-rstudios-package-installation-on-windows-10-c1e602bf3a1f which seems to be the same as discussed here [R not finding package even after package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407092/r-not-finding-package-even-after-package-installation)
However when I open the .RProfile file I cannot find the line suggested and the text seems different.
I have installed R version 4.2.0 and wondered if this file had been changed to try to deal with this OneDrive problem.
As a complete beginner would appreciate any advice. In meantime I am seeking to try to remove myself from dependence on OneDrive due to its annoying imperialist tendancies