# is there a way to avoid having to install packages every time in R?

Tags: r, installation, package, project, install.packages

I looked around and googled everything I could think of but cannot find a solution to what seems to be a basic problem.
I am new to R, and I am working on a couple of projects, from various computers.
Every time I open a project, I need to reinstall the various packages, and to activate them one by one with the library command.
Is there a way to 'save' the installed packages and to save the active ones in the library of a project?
thanks!
Giulia

Comment: You can save a [workspace](https://www.statmethods.net/interface/workspace.html) and load it every time.

Comment: You should only need to run `install.pacakges` once per computer. But you do have to load them each time with `library()` What exactly are the errors you are getting that make you think you need to re-install? What type of "projects" are you using? Is this an Rstudio thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300769/how-to-load-packages-in-r-automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load packages in R automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300769/how-to-load-packages-in-r-automatically)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [How to load packages in R automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300769/how-to-load-packages-in-r-automatically). The problem is not that OP needs to load packages with `library()` repeatedly; that is fine. The problem is that OP must *reinstall* various packages repeatedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `packrat` package was made just for this (https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/). It allows you to create self cointained projects. Besides not having to install every package again this is desirable because even having different package verions could lead to having different results on each computer.

Comment: Nice package to check out! I sometimes add what `sessionInfo()` throws as a comment to my code when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Install only Packages that are not already available in the system.

```
#Installing Packages that are not already available in the system 
list.of.packages <- c("ggplot2","readr","magrittr","dplyr","lubridate","DataExplorer","gmailr","purrr","DT","plotly","shinycssloaders","rgdal","shinythemes","magrittr")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
```