# Remove duplicates from R file

Tags: r

I have a .R file where I have duplicate entries as shown below,

lib.R

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)


library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
```

But Is there a way to make sure, this duplicates can be removed .
Expected output

lib.R

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
```

Comment: You could do a round trip of copying the content of your script, then read it in from clipboard, de-duplicate and write the result back to the clipboard from where you can then paste it back to your script.

Comment: Try: `writeLines(unique(readLines("lib.R")), "lib.R")`

Comment: What you really need is to put your favourite packages into [.Rprofile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300769/how-to-load-packages-in-r-automatically), so they are preload every time you start R.

Comment: @zx8754 did not get you . Can you explain please?